# Google App Engine: Implementing a collection of ordered lists

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to quickly implement a simple hi-score service in App Engine. Here are the two model classes:

```
class Hiscore(db.Model):
    time = db.DateTimeProperty()
    playerName = db.StringProperty()
    score = db.IntegerProperty()

class HiscoreTable(db.Model):
    countryCode = db.StringProperty()
    scores = db.ListProperty(???)
```

**Question 1**: How exactly do I use 'ListProperty'? It's hard to find examples.

**Question 2**: Is there a way to ensure the HiscoreTables are ordered by the 'score' property of each member score? And can I automatically limit the list to, say, 100 entries?

Many thanks,

Reuben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListProperty is a list of python objects, plain and simple. If I understand your question correctly what you are describing is a list of Hiscores within the HiscoreTable

<s>scores = db.ListProperty(Hiscore)</s>

For sorting you would have to use `sorted` to sort the list by score before writing the HiscoreTable entity. What it would be doing is the equivalent of pickling whatever Hiscore objects you add to the list, and retrieving those same pickled version on subsequent queries. Essentially it would be a list of snapshots of previous Hiscore rankings states, not the current state. If your intention is to cache the scores for a period of time then that would work - but you might consider using memcache instead.

Alternately, in order to reference the actual Hiscore entities you could do this

```
scores = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

and retrieve the Hiscore's by their keys. Again you would want to use `sorted` to sort the list before writing it which would store a snapshot of rankings when the HiscoreTable was written.

But if what you require are absolutely up to date score-tables per country then you will have to query the Hiscore model directly every time.

```
query.filter('countryCode =', somecode).order('-score').fetch(limit=100)
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this cos it sounds right, but I've basically made an executive decision to go back to PHP & MySQL. It's just too complex to do simple things, and I'm hearing way too many anecdotes about unreasonable billing. :\

Comment: AFAIK, `db.ListProperty(Hiscore)` would not work, because in case of Datastore, ListProperty can only contain supported types: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ListProperty

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to do it:

1. `HicoreTable` contains a list of `Hiscore` keys:

   ```
   scores = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
   ```

   In this case you are limited by the max number of index on an entity: 5000
2. Each `Hiscore` has a reference to the `HiscoreTable` it belongs to:

   ```
   class Hiscore(db.Model):
       hiscoreTable = db. ReferenceProperty(HiscoreTable)
   ```